# HTTP Header Issue

Tags: iis-7, asp.net, http

We've been having weird issues with our web server. Sometimes when you click around you will get the http header in plain text on the web page.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0 X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 26 Oct 2009 21:43:57 GMT
Content-Length: 13633
```

Anyone know why this would show up in the page content?

Comment: Hmm... is there server side caching going on or something?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @djangofan's comment.  It looks like you have a caching server or caching enabled.  Are you using ARR or a cache server or some other type of caching?  I know that ARR 1.0 had a caching bug that would cause this.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of feedback. The serverfault notifications were being caught by postini.
We do have Static Content Compression enabled through IIS 7. Other than that I don't think we use caching at all. I'll look on our sonicwall to see if there are any caching settings enabled.

Thanks for your feedback guys.

Answer (score 1):

Is the server sending two headers? If the server sends "200 OK Content-Type: text/plain" and then later sends the correct header, your browser will think the second header is actually content.  You could use a packet capturing tool to verify.